# Codebehind for ControlTemplate of lookless control?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, code-behind, controltemplate

I'm writing a lookless control which uses the usual Generic.xaml to apply a default control template.

This control template needs some codebehind in order to render itself (Mainly to respond to resize events), but I'm confused where the heck I'm supposed to put the code, and how I access the template from it.

This code is for rendering this particular template only, so does not belong in the control itself.

Can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: What do you mean by "render" itself? Are you override OnRender or just changing the layout as it resizes?

Comment: Yes, if this was a UserControl I would just override OnRender(), but I don't know where to put the code when it's a ControlTemplate being applied by a style in generic dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an excellent link that solves this using an attached behaviour on the template to attach a ViewModel that provides the extra functionality. This way the control itself remains completely unaware of any template specific logic:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/08/developing-a-very-lookless-silverlight-radial-gauge-control/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [link](http://drwpf.com/blog/2009/05/12/itemscontrol-l-is-for-lookless/) that might help you

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the OnRender method in your Control, just like in a UserControl. The element in your ControlTemplate though will appear on top of anything rendered by your Control.

If you need to add custom rendering above or in between elements in your ControlTemplate, then you'd have to use a secondary element as a named part. An example of named parts can be found in this [blog](http://utahdnug.org/blogs/xamlcoder/archive/2007/12/13/building-custom-template-able-wpf-controls.aspx) or in [mdm20's link](http://drwpf.com/blog/2009/05/12/itemscontrol-l-is-for-lookless/) (search for "PART_").

You'd then have that secondary element perform the rendering, possibly based on settings passed down from your control.

Comment: Many thanks, but I can't override OnRender of my control. As I said, this code is required for a particular template used by the control, not the control itself.

Comment: @Gaz - Is there more than one template? What is different between the "particular template" and the others?

Comment: There will be more than one yes. This particular template is just another look for the control like all the others, but this particular look is not expressible in XAML only, and needs code behind. It's where to put this code behind that I'm unsure of.

Comment: @Gaz - Then you'd probably need to use a secondary element/control. You'd then include that element in your ControlTemplate and give it a known name like "PART_CustomRender". In your primary control's OnApplyTemplate, you can get access to the secondary element.

Comment: Many thanks for your time. I really appreciate it, but I think I've found a solution that doesn't need a second control. (See my answer)